# How to resolve the array index out of bound exception in android

Tags: java, android

I am getting error in `doInBackground(String... params)` method, while I am calling the web-service. I am trying to write the following code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_colony_);
    new AddColony_LoaderTask().execute();

    add_colony_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_colony);
    note_Text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.note_text);
    btn_add_Colony_back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_colony_back);
    btnSave=(Button) findViewById(R.id.save_note);

    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/cabin.regular.ttf");
    add_colony_title.setTypeface(font1); add_colony_title.setTextSize(18.0f);
    btnSave.setTypeface(font1);btnSave.setTextSize(18.0f);
    note_Text.setTypeface(font1);note_Text.setTextSize(15.0f);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extras == null) {
            bookmarkid = null;
            note_type = null;


        } else {
            bookmarkid = extras.getString("bookmarkid");
            note_type = extras.getString("note_type");

        }
    } else {
        bookmarkid = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("bookmarkid");
        note_type = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("note_type");

    }

    System.out.println(bookmarkid);
    System.out.println(note_type);

    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(in);

            new AddColony_LoaderTask().execute("https://www.mysites.com/secure-mobile/note?"," access_token",bookmarkid,note_type);
        }
    });


}




class AddColony_LoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        bookmarkid = params[2];
        note_type = params[3];
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String jsonResult = "";
        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", "94529e5dbc6234fc3bbfce7406b8dde9"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bookmarkId",bookmarkid));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("note",note_type));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            int status = 200;

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                System.out.println(data);

                System.out.println("fffff");
                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsono.length(); i++)
                {

                }
                return null;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it shows the following error at line `bookmarkid = params[2];` while the app is run

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.example.mysite.myhive_app, PID: 13842
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=3
    at com.example.mysite.myhive_app.AddColony_Activity$AddColony_LoaderTask.doInBackground(AddColony_Activity.java:119)
    at com.example.mysite.myhive_app.AddColony_Activity$AddColony_LoaderTask.doInBackground(AddColony_Activity.java:114)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: you are not getting any params there. Trying printing the data to the method you'll understand.

Comment: `AddColony_Activity.java:119` where it is??

Comment: @ELITE it giviing error in this line     bookmarkid = params[2]; and AddColony_Activity.java:119 is this line class AddColony_LoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>

Comment: @Pawan check the answer, i added the cause of exception.

Comment: Since the error is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=3`, it's not the line saying `bookmarkid = params[2]`, because that would be index 2, not index 3. And it is not the next line saying `note_type = params[3]`, which does use index 3, because error says length is 0, so the first line would have failed first. Are you sure you're running that version of the code. Recompile and redeploy to make sure.

Comment: @Andreas he is executing the `AsyncTask` without passing any parameters in `onCreate` method..

Comment: @ELITE So `params` is an empty array, which is in line with the `length=0` part of the error message, but error at `params[2]` is inconsistent with error text of `index=3`, so there is also a code refresh issue in play. *That* code with not throw *that* error at *that* line. It may not be the real issue, but it is also an issue, which is what my comment was all about.

Answer (score 1):

check your `onCreate` method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_colony_);
    new AddColony_LoaderTask().execute(); // here is the cause

    add_colony_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_colony);
```

you are executing task without passing any parameters. So the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

you are just executing the Asynchtask without passing any data.

```
 new AddColony_LoaderTask().execute();
```

do this

```
String[] query=new String[3];
        query[0]=requestURL;
        query[1]=access_token;
        query[2]= bookmarkid;
        query[3]= note_type;
  new AddColony_LoaderTask().execute(query);
```

Comment: getting same error

Comment: have you even passed values in those variables?

Comment: i missed the access_token param. check adding that

Comment: I corrected that but still same error

Comment: `execute()` is a varargs, so you can just do `execute(requestURL, access_token, bookmarkid, note_type)`. Anyway, your updated code still fails because you're still only allocating `String[3]`. Needs to be `String[4]` if you do it that way, but varargs is far easier.

Comment: @PawanThakur You should also note that you cannot pass those values up there, because they haven't been loaded with the right values yet.

Comment: @Andreas  ok let me pass in this waynew AddColony_LoaderTask().execute("https://www.mysites.com/secure-mobile/note?"," access_token",bookmarkid,note_type);
        }  Bookmarkid conatin the value. I passes these value from other actvity.  System.out.println(bookmarkid); printed value now i am passing theses values in array.Can you sugggested me other way